# jest puppeteer how to use setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jestjs, puppeteer, jest-puppeteer

I am a newbie at running Jest puppeteer.

I'm trying to run a test suite locally that I did not write.

All the tests fail to run and I get this error pointing at beforeEach...

"beforeEach(async () => {"

"thrown: "Exceeded timeout of 5000 ms for a hook.
Use jest.setTimeout(newTimeout) to increase the timeout value, if this is a long-running test.""

Where / how exactly should I place the setTimeout?

Is there something else I am missing or have in the wrong spot?

```
const baseURL = "http://localhost:1234";
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

beforeEach(() => {
  // Reset mock function's states before each test.
  jest.clearAllMocks();
});


describe("chatbot", () => {
  beforeEach(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false, slowMo: 250,});
    const page = await browser.newPage();

  
    await page.goto(baseURL, { waitUntil: "load" });
    // set the fade-ins to 0 ms to prevent timeouts in tests
    await page.evaluate(() => { window.animationDelay = 0 })
    await page.click("#chat-circle");

    await browser.close()
  });



  it("should show contact info when the user enters 'contact'", async () => {
    // submit the form with a message, expect to see the response
    const message = "contact";
    await page.evaluate(() => {
      // get this same const in the page's context
      const message = "contact";
      $("#chat-input").val(message)
    });
    await page.click("#chat-submit");
    await expect(page).toMatch("We have 24 hour phone support. Our phone number is +01 312 555 8432. We look forward to hearing from you!");
  });

  it("should show credit card help message when the user enters 'credit card'", async () => {
    // submit the form with a message, expect to see the response
    const message = "credit card";
    await page.evaluate(() => {
      // get this same const in the page's context
      const message = "credit card";
      $("#chat-input").val(message)
    });
    await page.click("#chat-submit");
    await expect(page).toMatch("You can pay with any major credit card. Enter your card details and billing address at checkout.");
  });

  it("should show payment help message when the user enters 'payment'", async () => {
    // submit the form with a message, expect to see the response
    const message = "payment";
    await page.evaluate(() => {
      // get this same const in the page's context
      const message = "payment";
      $("#chat-input").val(message)
    });
    await page.click("#chat-submit");
    await expect(page).toMatch("We have three payment options: credit card, paypal, or apple pay. Choose your preferred method at checkout.");
  });

  it("should show help options when the users enters 'help'", async () => {
    // submit the form with a message, expect to see the response
    const message = "help";
    await page.evaluate(() => {
      // get this same const in the page's context
      const message = "help";
      $("#chat-input").val(message)
    });
    await page.click("#chat-submit");
    await expect(page).toMatch("Enter a keyword for help with a topic: contact, payment, credit card, destinations.");
  });
});
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to place it on the top

```js
const baseURL = "http://localhost:1234";
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

jest.setTimeout(500000);

beforeEach(() => {
  // Reset mock function's states before each test.
  jest.clearAllMocks();
});

....
```